# Why is this server redirecting to another page?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect

I am building a site for a client. For a reason unknown to me www.domain.com forwards to www.domain.com/directory/home.html. If i type www.domain.com/index.php it works correctly. I have checked .htaccess there was nothing there, so I set the index to index.php which works fine in every directory other than the root directory. I have root access and have checked the httpd.conf (did a search in VI for the document that I was being redirected to) and anything else I could think of. Where should I look next? The server is a VPS running CentOS 5.5 with multiple domains, has CPanel WHM 11 for root access and CPanel X installed for each domain.

Comment: Also, the client says he did not set up and redirection or forwarding on this domain.

Comment: Did you check DNS?

Answer (score 1):

It could be another index.* file (HTML) in the root dir with an HTTP Redirect directive.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Firefox, there's an extension called 'Live HTTP Headers' which will give you a window into what the server is telling your browser about URL resolution and redirection; I've used this before to catch weird mod_rewrite stuff, which would be my first suspect for the culprit behind your problem. There may be a stanza in httpd.conf which redirects to a relative path, which your vim search might not have caught. Good luck; I hope this helps.